# clang-format array initialiser with brace on next line

Tags: c++, clang-format

When trying to initialise an array or std::vector, for example, I'd like for the first brace to be placed on the following line. My current brace style is "Allman", but this doesn't seem to work.

In my case, instead of:

```
    std::vector<LveModel::Vertex> vertices{
        {{0.0f, -0.5f}},
        {{0.5f, 0.5f}},
        {{-0.5f, 0.5f}},
    };
```

I would like

```
    std::vector<LveModel::Vertex> vertices
    {
        {{0.0f, -0.5f}},
        {{0.5f, 0.5f}},
        {{-0.5f, 0.5f}},
    };
```

Is there an option for this? I cannot seem to find it in the clang-format documentation